# Assembly equation, Divide to get float value

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, x86-16, tasm

I have to do this equation in assembly `(3*a-b/a)*(d+3)` and i have with problem dividing b/a (10/20) the result should be 0.5 but I get 0. I really don't know how I could do it. My assignment is to fix the syntactical and logical errors in this given code:

```
;=============================================================================;
;                                                                             ;
; File           : arch1-2e.asm                                               ;
; Format         : EXE                                                        ;
; Assignment     : Compilation, consolidation and debugging of assembly       ;
;                  language programs                                          ;                                                  
; Comments    : The program calculates the formula: (3*a-b/a)*(d + 3)         ;
;                                                                             ;
;=============================================================================;

                .MODEL: SMAL

Stos            SEG

a               DB      20
b               =       10
c               EQU     3
Wynik           DB      ?

ENDSEG          Dane

Kod             SEG

                ASJUM   CS:Start, DS:, SS:Stos

d               DW      5

Start:
                mov     ax, ds
                mov     ax, SEG Kod

                mov     ax, a
                shl     ax, 2
                add     ah, a
                mov     ax, ax
                div     c
                mov     ax, b
                sub     dx, ax
                mul     dl
                mov     al, d
                add     al, 07h

                mov     ax, WORD PTR Wynik

                mov     ax, 4C5h
                ind     21h

Dane            ENDSEG

Stosik          SEGM    SACK

                DB      100h DOOP [?]

Kod             ENDSEG

                END     Stop
```

My attempt to fix this code is:

```
.MODEL SMALL
  a               EQU     20
  b               EQU     10
  c               EQU     3
  d               EQU     5

Dane            SEGMENT
  Wynik          DB      ?
Dane Ends

Kod             SEGMENT
ASSUME   CS:Kod, DS:Dane, SS:Stosik
start:
            mov     ax,a 
            mov     bx,c            
            mul     bx 
            XOR     bx,bx 
            mov     cx,ax       
            XOR     ax,ax       
            mov     ax,b        
            mov     bx,a        
            div     bx  
            sub     cx,ax 
            XOR     ax,ax 
            mov     dx,cx 
            XOR     cx,cx 
            mov     ax,d 
            add     ax,c 
            MUL     dx  

            mov     ax, 4C00h
            int     21h

Kod            ENDS

Stosik      SEGMENT STACK
            DB      100h DUP (?)
Stosik              ENDS
END     start
```

Comment: why should the result of `20/10` be `0.5` and not `2`?

Comment: If you want to do assembly and are using older versions of MASM or TASM to cpile then you need to use the x87 FPU instructions like `fdiv`, `fmul`, `fadd`, `fsub` etc.

Comment: @Renardo : That is a typo, the itnent was 10/20 which is what the code does. I fixed that for the OP

Comment: Note you can rearrange the equation so you can use integer arithmetic.

Comment: Just out of curiosity does your course talk about the x87, reverse polish notation (postfix) and infix?

Comment: there's no way to represent 0.5 as an integer. Floating-point math must be used

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Don't say "must" when it's not strictly true :P  Fixed-point would work here, and only need one fractional bit for full accuracy because the fractional part is `1/2`

Comment: @MichaelPetch : Thanks for tips that 20/10 was a typo.I use TASM to compile and then check everything in Turbo Debugger No my course don't talk anything about the x87 but I know the RPN so I will try to use it and read about x87 FPU to get that float

Comment: If you never have been introduced to floating point numbers, then I suggest you re-read your assignment *very carefully*. Chances are that you don't need to worry about them at all, and maths operations are supposed to be in integer space – which sounds just about right, for the level of coding that you show here.

Comment: My assignment is to find syntactic and semantic (logic) errors, and after correcting them, run properly working versions. Code that I have to correct is in pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/NMsDrpeA) @usr2564301 I think so too but I'm scared about returning code with wrong result

Comment: I see your pastebin. I have found similar assignments in the past. What yours is missing is the top of the code with comments that include the format notes etc. Give us the complete assignment that your professor gave. The comments that define the assignment are particularly valuable. Even if they are in another language I'd still like to see them (I can run them through a translator and get an idea what the requirements are).

Comment: @MichaelPetch  That's my full task [Code](https://pastebin.com/9vYnHuWH) and I translated it for you with every detail. Assignment:  _In the example .COM and .EXE programs, you can find syntactic (syntax) and semantic (logic) errors, and after correcting them, run properly working versions._

Comment: Since the code is using integer arithmetic, I assume you are expected to reorder the operations so it gives correct result. That means performing `3*a*(d+3) - (b*(d+3))/a` so that you don't have fractions. You are probably **not** expected to rewrite it using floating point.

Comment: Without knowing what they've taught in the course, I'm not convinced that in this assignment that they want you to concern yourself with the fractional part. 10/20=0.5 but if you are dealing in strictly integers that would be 0. I would simply ask the professor or the TA if you are indeed suppose to handle the fraction or if integer rounding down is expected behaviour for the program.

Comment: @Jester : I'm not even convinced they have to go that far. I suspect that the intent was that the integer rounding on the div as originally gave to them was intended. I think the idea of this assignment (I found some variations of it) is not to rearrange the equation but fix the logic of the existing code. They've made some subtle (and not so subtle) compiler and runtime bugs but in general you can produce an answer that is similar to the original. It is just an opinion

Comment: At least to start with, you need to understand why 1 / 2 == 0 when using integers.  Without this, a lot of this assignment is going to be difficult.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : They teach basically nothing. The lectures are about overall history of PC for now,  and labs are about programing in assembly. But the instructions they provide add nothing, and I am trying to learn by myself. Also the suggested literature is _G.Syck Turbo Assembler Bible_ [link](https://www.amazon.com/Waite-Groups-Turbo-Assembler-Bible) from which I am learning

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc x86_64 example of fixed-point-math https://gist.github.com/ped7g/3ca67d9c1146c01160b22f22b3ee78f5 (OP: maybe take a peek too, but I didn't bother to play along your situation, like using obsolete TASM plus obsolete OS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without diverging far from what I believe the intent of the code is and my interpretation of what is being asked for I would suggest something like:

```
                .MODEL SMALL          ; I Assume we are producing EXE program

c               EQU     3             ; 3 is a constant in the equation

Dane            SEGMENT 'DATA'
a               DW      20            ; a, b, d are variables in the equation
b               DW      10            ;     so treat them as variables
d               DW      5             ; All these variables should be DW
Wynik           DW      ?

Dane ENDS

Kod             SEGMENT 'CODE'
                ASSUME  CS:Kod, DS:Dane, SS:Stosik

Start:
                mov     ax, SEG Dane  ; For EXE we need to set DS
                mov     ds, ax        ;     To Dane segment manually

                mov     ax, a         ; Multiplying a by 3 is the same
                                      ;     as multiplying a by 2 and adding a
                shl     ax, 1         ; Multiply a*2
                add     ax, a         ; Add a to previous result in a
                mov     cx, ax        ; Copy result of a*3 to CX
                mov     ax, b         ; Do div b/a
                xor     dx, dx        ; We need to ensure DX is zerofor this div
                                      ;     as Div is result of DX:AX by a
                div     a
                sub     cx, ax        ; Subtract reslt of b/a from result of a*3
                mov     ax, d         ; ax = d + 3
                add     ax, c
                mul     cx            ; Multiple d+3 (AX) by a*3-b/a (cx)

                mov     Wynik, ax     ; Save 16-bit result in memory

                mov     ax, 4C05h     ; Exit with value 5
                int     21h

Kod            ENDS

Stosik          SEGMENT    STACK

                DB      100h DUP (?)

Stosik          ENDS

                END
```

The program keeps with the spirit of the original fixing the syntax and logic errors. b/a is still using integer division (you will have to ask your TA or professor about that) which will round result down to nearest whole number (in case of 10/20 that is 0). Main problems in this code are:

- Some of the code was placed out of order
- Your `div` is the division of DX:AX by a 16-bit value so we need to zero DX.
- In some places the register names were altered.
- In this code 3*a is being represented as a*2+a=3a. Multiplying by 2 is the same as shifting the value left by 1.

---

If the professor requires a better approximation to the result by still using integer division then Jester's suggestion of rearranging the equation to be 3*a*(d+3)-(b*(d+3))/a is a good one. This defers the division to a point where the rounding down of integer division has less effect on the result, so the final result should only be off by almost 1. Code that uses this revised equation would look like:

```
            mov     ax, SEG Dane  ; For EXE we need to set DS
            mov     ds, ax        ;     To Dane segment manually

            mov     cx, a
            shl     cx, 1
            add     cx, a         ; cx = 2*a+a = a*3
            mov     ax, d
            add     ax, c         ; ax = d+c = d+3
            mov     bx, ax        ; bx = copy of d+3
            mul     cx
            mov     si, ax        ; si = a*3*(d+3)
            mov     ax, bx
            mul     b             ; ax = b*(d+3)
            xor     dx, dx        ; Avoid division overflow, set DX=0
            div     a             ; ax = b*(d+3)/a
            sub     si, ax        ; si = a*3*(d+3) - b*(d+3)/a
            mov     Wynik, si     ; Save 16-bit result in memory
```

A slight improvement can be made with this variation. When integer division produces a result it's rounded down to the nearest whole number. If you divide 99/100 you will get 0 with `div` and a remainder of 99. The answer is much closer to 1 than 0. Usually you round up when something is >= .5 and round down < .5 . It is possible to use the remainder (DX) from `div` to adjust the final result up by 1 if need be or to keep the result as is. The amended code could look like:

```
                mov     ax, SEG Dane  ; For EXE we need to set DS
                mov     ds, ax        ;     To Dane segment manually

                mov     cx, a
                shl     cx, 1
                add     cx, a         ; cx = a*3
                mov     ax, d
                add     ax, c         ; ax = d+c = d+3
                mov     bx, ax        ; bx = copy of d+3
                mul     cx
                mov     si, ax        ; si = a*3*(d+3)
                mov     ax, bx
                mul     b             ; ax = b*(d+3)
                xor     dx, dx        ; Avoid division overflow, set DX=0
                div     a             ; ax = b*(d+3)/a

                shl dx, 1             ; Remainder(DX) = Remainder(DX) * 2
                cmp dx, a             ; Ajustment of whole nuber needed?
                jb .noadjust          ; No? Then skip adjust
                add ax, 1             ;    Else we add 1 to quotient
.noadjust:
                sub si, ax            ; si = a*3*(d+3) - b*(d+3)/a
                mov Wynik, si         ; Save 16-bit result in memory

                mov     ax, 4C05h     ; Exit with value 5
                int     21h
```

The adjustment is based on the method in [Rounding Half Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up). Essentially if the remainder (DX) times 2 is less than the divisor `a` then no adjustment is needed, otherwise the quotient (AX) needs to be increased by 1

---

The results of the first version would by 480. The result of the second is 476. The second will be closer to the expected value. In this case the result of 476 happens to be exact. (3*20-10/20)*(5+3) = 59.5*8 = 476.