# Assembly program compilation error

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, dos, x86-16, tasm

I have a problem with following 16-bit TASM program which evaluates the expression (a*b+c*d)/(a-d):

```
MyCode          SEGMENT     

            ORG      100h
            ASSUME  CS:SEGMENT MyCode, DS:SEGMENT MyCode, SS:SEGMENT

Start:
            jmp      Beginning

a               DB      20
b               EQU     10
c               DW      5
d               =       3
Result          DB      ?

Beginning:
            mov     al, a    
            mov     bl, b    
            mov     dx,ax    
            mov     al, BYTE PTR c    
            mov     bl, d    
            mul     bl        
            add     dx,ax   
            mov     al, a     
            sub     al,bl    
            mov     bl,al    
            mov     ax,dx    
            div     bl        

            mov     Result, al 

            mov     ax, 4C00h
            int     21h

MyCode          ENDS

            END Start
```

The compilation errors I get in DOSBox console state that there's an undefined symbol (SEGMENT) and that the compiler can't address with currently ASSUMEd segment registers. It seems to me that that I'm missing the definition of a block, but I have no idea how to proceed further. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: This other answer may provide some help for your assignment:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283212/3857942 . It is the same assignment as this but you have have translated the code from Polish? to english for us. Thanks

Comment: The direct cause of the problem is that `ASSUME` does not need the `SEGMENT` keyword. So instead of `ASSUME  CS:SEGMENT MyCode` you should write `ASSUME  CS:MyCode` and so on.

Comment: @MichaelPetch he does he just cut it out of the formatting, let me fix it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch it's very similar, I was told to correct those errors as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't fix the logical errors for you, but the syntax in the top of this code is incorrect:

```
MyCode          SEGMENT     

            ORG      100h
            ASSUME  CS:SEGMENT MyCode, DS:SEGMENT MyCode, SS:SEGMENT

Start:
```

You don't use the directive `SEGMENT` in the assume, they have to be removed. When removed the segments have to have a name applied to them. One is missing on `SS:`. It should look like:

```
MyCode          SEGMENT

            ASSUME  CS:MyCode, DS:MyCode, SS:MyCode
            ORG      100h

Start:
```

In DOS COM program all the segments for DATA, CODE, and the STACK are in the same segment. You can also achieve the same by replacing it with:

```
.model tiny
.code
ORG 100h
Start:
```

The TINY model is designed to work for DOS COM program creation. The `ORG 100h` directive has to be preceded by the `.code` directive. With this modification you have to **remove** this line:

```
MyCode          ENDS
```

Answer (score 0):

L1: .model small
L2: .stack
L3: .data
L4:  printStr db "Pangasinan State University"
L5: .code
L6: BEGIN:
L7:     mov dx,OFFSET printString
L8:     mov ax,SEG printStr
L9:     mov ds,ax
L10:    mov ah,9H
L11:    int 21H
L12:    mov ah, 4ch
L13:    int 21D
L14: END BEGIN

Comment: Please reformat this code, and explain how it addresses the original question